# Book about female character who can see in the past

Tags: identification-request

Read this when I was very young, so I don't remember it too well. But it was about a young woman who met a guy and was being introduced into his family, however she could see back in time through some kind of strange ability. The family had a dark past and the mother of the guy tried to kill her, saying "you see through time too well" or "you are too good at seeing the past". She did not succeed.

That's all I can remember. It also had a lot to with hourglasses.

Publish Date
Not sure - but I read it about 20 years ago.

No clue the title.

No clue the author, but I'd guess female since the main character was female.